# Print() function failing to output vector, whats wrong?

Tags: c++, function, vector

So my job is to describe the functions that our teacher only gave us prototypes to for a phonebook assignment. He also gave us a built `main()` and we are not allowed to change his `main()` or prototypes, only describe them.  I'm working on the `void print()` function, the one near the bottom. The `cout` brackets `<<` are marked as an error. And if you guys have any tips on the `void erase()` function as well, I though of using the `void lookup()` function inside the `erase()`, but the problem is I'm supposed to erase the index and the lookup function returns the phone number, not the index.
Listed first is the prototypes, then my work, then the main.

PROTOYPES

```
    #ifndef PHONEBOOK_H
    #define PHONEBOOK_H
    #include <string>
    #include <vector>
    using namespace std;

    class Person
    {
    public:
        Person();
        Person(string new_name, int new_phone);
        string get_name() const;
        int get_phone() const;
        bool operator < (Person p) const;
        void print() const;

    private:
        string name;
        int phone;
    };

    void add_people(vector<Person> &phone_book);
    void erase(vector<Person> &phone_book, string name);
    void sort(vector<Person> &phone_book);
    void shuffle(vector<Person> &phone_book);
    void reverse(vector<Person> &phone_book);
    void print(vector<Person> &phone_book);
    int lookup(const vector<Person> &phone_book, string name);
    #endif
```

MY WORK

```
        #include <iostream>
        #include <string>
        #include <vector>
        #include <time.h>
        #include "phonebook.h"

        Person::Person()
        {
            name = "NONE";
            phone = 0000000;

        }
        Person::Person(string new_name, int new_phone)
        {
            name=new_name;
            phone=new_phone;
        }
        string Person::get_name() const
        {
            return name;
        }
        int Person::get_phone() const
        {
            return phone;
        }
        bool Person::operator < (Person p) const
        {
            return name < p.name;
        }
        void Person::print() const
        {
            cout << endl << name << " " << phone;
        }

        void add_people(vector<Person> &phone_book)
        {
            cout << "Please enter the new name: ";
            string s;
            getline(cin, s);
            cout << "Please enter new number: ";
            int number;
            cin >> number;
            phone_book.push_back(Person(s,number));
        }
        void erase(vector<Person> &phone_book, string name)
        {   
        }
        void sort(vector<Person> &phone_book)
        {
        }
        void shuffle(vector<Person> &phone_book)
        {
        }
        void reverse(vector<Person> &phone_book)
        {
        }
        void print(vector<Person> &phone_book)
        {
            for(int i=0; i < phone_book.size(); i++)
                cout << phone_book[i] << " ";
        }

        int lookup(const vector<Person> &phone_book, string name)
        {
                int i = 0;
                while (i < phone_book.size() && phone_book[i].get_name() != name)
                {
                    i++;
                    return phone_book[i].get_phone();
                }
        }
```

THE MAIN

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <time.h>
#include "phonebook.h"

using namespace std;




int main()
{

    vector<Person> phone_book;
    string name;
    int number;
    int answer;

    srand((int)(time(0)));

    phone_book.push_back(Person("Bruin, Joe", 5556456));
    phone_book.push_back(Person("Simpson, Homer", 5557471));
    phone_book.push_back(Person("Duffman, Barry", 5533331));


    cout <<"\n";
    cout << "Your phone book contains the following names and numbers: \n";

    for (int i=0; i < phone_book.size(); i++)
    {

        phone_book[i].print();
        cout << "\n";
    }
    cout <<"\n";
    answer=0;

    while (answer != 8)
    {
        cout << "\nChoose from the following options:\n\n";

        cout << "1) Add people to the phone book.\n";
        cout << "2) Erase a person from the phone book.\n";
        cout << "3) Sort the phone book.\n";
        cout << "4) Shuffle the phone book.\n";
        cout << "5) Reverse the phone book.\n";
        cout << "6) Print the phone book.\n";
        cout << "7) Look up a person in the phone book.\n";
        cout << "8) Quit.\n\n";

        cin >> answer;

        string clear;

        getline(cin, clear);

        if (answer == 1)
            add_people(phone_book);
        else if (answer == 2)
        {
            cout << "Enter a name: ";
            getline(cin, name);
            erase(phone_book, name);

        }
        else if (answer == 3)
            sort(phone_book);
        else if (answer == 4)
            shuffle (phone_book);
        else if (answer == 5)
            reverse(phone_book);
        else if (answer == 6)
        {
            cout <<"\n";
            cout << "Your phone book contains the following names and numbers: \n";
            print(phone_book);
        }
        else if (answer ==7)
        {                   
            cout << "Enter a name: ";
            getline(cin, name);
            int number = lookup(phone_book, name); 
            if (number > 0)
            {
                cout << "\n\nThe number for " << name << " is: " << number << "\n\n";
            }
            else
                cout << name << " not found in the phone book.\n";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `Person` does not [overload the `<<` operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1z2f6c2k.aspx). So you either you have to overload it, or you have to `cout` the members of the class separately (which is basically the same but overloading the `<<` operator is nicer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cout << phone_book[i] << " ";
```

is a problem since `operator<<` is not defined between `cout` and a `Person`. You can fix the problem by defining such a function or calling `Person::print` in the loop.

```
void print(vector<Person> &phone_book)
{
    for(int i=0; i < phone_book.size(); i++)
    {
        phone_book[i].print();
        cout << " ";
    }
}
```

**Suggestion for improvement**

Don't assume `cout` or `cin` anywhere in the class. Wherever you use one of those in the class implementations, change the functions to use `std::ostream&` and `std::istream&` as input arguments. Then, you can choose to use any `std::ostream` or `std::istream` when calling the functions. You may decide to read the data from a file, or write the data to a file. Make that decision in `main` and keep the classes free from that decision.

As examples, change `Person::print()` to:

```
void print(std::ostream& out) const;
```

and the implementation to:

```
void Person::print(std::ostream& out) const
{
    out << endl << name << " " << phone;
}
```

Change the non-member function `print` to:

```
void print(vector<Person> &phone_book, std::ostream& out)
{
    for(int i=0; i < phone_book.size(); i++)
    {
        phone_book[i].print(out);
        out << " ";
    }
}
```

Comment: Great the first method worked, I had forgotten I had a class function for printing!!! I would change the parameters if I could but he strictly specified to maintain the paramters he provided

Comment: @BroBama, that's unfortunate that some instructors are not paying attention to such details.

Answer (score 0):

```
cout << phone_book[i] << " ";
```

This line doesn't make sense. phone_book is a vector of Persons, so how do you expect `cout` to print an entire person?! To fix this, you have to tell it which member variable of person you would like it to print out. Unfortunately the following code won't work:

```
cout << phone_book[i].name << " - " << phone_book[i].phone << endl;
```

because the member variables `name` and `phone` have been made `private` (they cannot be accessed outside the class itself). Luckily, you happen to already have a function within the Person class that prints it for you:

```
void Person::print() const
{
    cout << endl << name << " " << phone;
}
```

If you call this function, it should print out the person's name and phone number. To call it, simply use:

```
for(int i=0; i < phone_book.size(); i++)
    phone_book[i].print();
```

Another method is to *overload* the `<<` operator - this basically means to redefine what it means to use `<<` on your class. For example, you could create a new datatype based on an integer, but overload the `+` operator so that it subtracted instead of added. I'll give you some example code:

```
class myVar
{
    public:
        int value;

    myVar operator+(myVar varToSubtract)
    {
        return value - varToSubtract;
    }
};
```

Same principle applies with `<<` - I'm sure you can figure out the rest yourself :)